# Order objects that contain a many-to-many field that need to be ordered beforehand in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've these two models:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Chat(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    messages = models.ManyToManyField('Message')
```

How do I order the chats by the last send message in each chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the `Chat` objects by the last (maximum) `timestamp` of the related `Message`s with:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Chat.objects.annotate(
    last_message=Max('messages__timestamp')
).order_by('-last_message')
```